# How to properly use on method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
jQuery('#sbox-window').on('change', '#filter-by-site', function(){
    console.log(jQuery(this).val());
    console.log('change');
});


<div id="sbox-window">
    <div id="sbox-content">
        <p>
            <select id="filter-by-site">
                <option value="null">Filter cameras by site</option>
                <option value="1">Site 1</option>
                <option value="2">Site 2</option>
                <option value="3">Site 3</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nothing happens... With deprecated `live()` all works fine. Where is problem?

Comment: works for me , be sure to use the latest version of jquery.

Comment: your code works what is the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/gaHhv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this works. 
Is it possible that you are attaching the event to "sbox-window" that is part of a Jquery Template or to some other means that generate the div dynamically?. 
Depending on the implementation the "sbox-window" div doesn't exist during the document, ready so you'll nee to bubble up to a higher Dom-Object--- worst case to the document... but I wouldn't recommend that... This is also why "live" works.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#sbox-window #filter-by-site', function(){
    console.log(jQuery(this).val());
    console.log('change');
});
```

Because when you do `jQuery('#sbox-window')` there is no such element yet (because DOM constructs sequentially and you define the block lower), so you call `on` method for empty array of elements, and of course there is no effect.

As was mentioned there is another option:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#sbox-window').on('change', '#filter-by-site', function(){
       console.log($(this).val());
       console.log('change');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yeqz6/2/)

The `on()` method has been added in jQuery version 1.7. Please make sure you've included a new enough version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe at time you are using delegation, `#sbox-window` is not already in DOM.
Wrap it in ready callback function:

```
$(function(){
   jQuery('#sbox-window').on('change', '#filter-by-site', function(){
       console.log(jQuery(this).val());
       console.log('change');
   });
});
```

.live() use document as delegate.

Comment: `#filter-by-site` is inside `#sbox-window`

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine, see a [**working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/AtncT/), so what you seem to lack it's execute your query code on a DOM ready handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#sbox-window').on('change', '#filter-by-site', function(){
       console.log($(this).val());
       console.log('change');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use $.bind on the  element.

Or, far better, you can do it without using jquery at all just with:

```
document.querySelector('#filter-by-site').addEventListener('change', changeHandler);

function changeHandler(e) {
    console.log('change');
}
```

Comment: Its not better as querySelector is not full cross browser (older browser)

Comment: Right but you can still use document.getElementById, still pure JS and crossbrowser

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way too:

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#filter-by-site', function(){
   console.log(jQuery(this).val());
   console.log('change');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use latest version of jquery library, its working fine

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```